# encode latin chars using ISO-8859-1 in PHP

Tags: php, url-encoding, iso-8859-1

I want to encode to ISO-8859-1 a url that contains latin characters like **à**, using PHP.

The encoded string will be used to perform a request to a webservice. So if the request is:

http://www.mywebservice.com?param=à

the encoded string should be:

http://www.mywebservice.com?param=%E0

I've tried using PHP's function **urlencode()** but it returns the input encoded in UTF-8:

http://www.mywebservice.com?param=%C3%A0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/utf8_decode) before `urlencode`:

```
urlencode(utf8_decode("à"))
```